# Ubuntu XWiki Tomcat Upgrade

Tags: server, postgresql, tomcat

```
System Information:
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.58 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Jan 6 1970 15:09:28 UTC
Server number:  9.0.58.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.15.0-58-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    11.0.17+8-post-Ubuntu-1ubuntu222.04
JVM Vendor:     Ubuntu
```

I have **xwiki** deployed in tomcat with a `.deb` package as provided from:

https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Installation/InstallationViaAPT/#HTomcatUsability

So there is PostgreSQL, tomcat, and wxiki in one package.
Now we have a security breach in the given tomcat version:

https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2022-45143
for jammy it says, `needs triage`, what does this mean?

From what I can see, it is not possible to update only tomcat 9.0.58.0 to 9.0.69.0